# Scala: Check if each node in an xml defines a parameter

Tags: xml, scala

I am using scala.xml library. In my example, I would like to check if each "student" defines the parameter "age" but it doesn't matter what the value is.
My test should return false in this case:

```
<student name="James"
     age="16"
     class="4C"
/>
<student name="Ellen"
     class="4C"
/>
```

But true in this one:

```
<student name="James"
     age="16"
     class="4C"
/>
<student name="Ellen"
     age="15"
/>
```

I tried something like this but it always return false:

```
var res : Boolean = true
for(node <- (xml \\ "student"))
{
  if(!(node.contains("age"))) res = false
}
res
```

I could have find a way to solve my problem but the syntax doesn't look very efficient. What do you think?

```
var res : Boolean = true
  for(node <- (xml \\ "student"))
    {
      if(!(node.attribute("age").nonEmpty)) res = false
    }
res
```

Comment: I tried to use the "exists" and "contains" function. But I wanted to do something like this: (xml \\ "student").exists(_ \@ "type") but the syntax is completely wrong. I am a newbie in scala and I didn't get the right syntax...

Comment: Please put any code you've tried into your question - it will be useful to let us know what you've done. Also, if you have any errors, compilation or runtime, please add them to the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

A more functional-programming oriented approach will make use of the `forall` method on `Seq` types to see if a given condition is true for all items within the sequence.

In your case, you want to know if the attribute `"age"` is defined for all of the `student` nodes.

```
val res = (xml \\ "student").forall(node => node.attribute("age").isDefined)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found something that works for me. I don't know if it is the best way to do it but it solved my problem so maybe it will solve someone else's too.

```
var res : Boolean = true
  for(node <- (xml \\ "student"))
    {
      if(!(node.attribute("age").isDefined)) res = false
    }
res
```